# Routes not working for new application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I created a new rails application a few days ago and got started by working on the models. I have a user model managed by devise and I am trying to get the login working. I began by setting the root to the user sessions controller like so:

```
root 'devise/sessions#new'
```

Then when I go to the root for my application in the browser it shows the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." page. I tried setting up a bogus route like:

```
get 'test/routes', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
```

and when I tried navigating to this route, I get the same error page. I checked the logs to see what was going on, and the problem is that nothing is going on. It doesn't seem like the router is even working because no page requests are showing up in the logs. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`devise_scope :user do` 
`root 'devise/sessions#new'` 
`end`
 should solve the issue.

Setting devise
/sessions#new as root is not a good idea.The devise/session#new redirect to '/' if the user is signed in.This will cause a redirect loop if the user is already signed in .
Its better if there is some consultation hub controller as root which checks whether the user is signed in and redirect to devise/session#new if he is not.

Comment: I think something else is wrong because I generated a scaffold and none of those routes work either. It always brings up the 500 error page.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on, but I think the problem has something to do with my nginx/passenger configuration. I started the default WEBrick server and everything worked perfectly. At least I narrowed it down that far, so thanks for your help.